# Prove $\frac{x}{y^3+2xyz} + \frac{y}{z^3+2xyz} + \frac{z}{x^3+2xyz} \gt \frac{15}{2}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

*Given $x,y,z$ is positive number that $x+y+z=1$. Prove that*

$$ P = \frac{x}{y^3+2xyz} + \frac{y}{z^3+2xyz} + \frac{z}{x^3+2xyz} \gt \frac{15}{2}$$

**My attempt:**
$$2xyz \leq \frac{2}{27}$$
$$ \Rightarrow P= \frac{x}{y^3+2xyz} + \frac{y}{z^3+2xyz} + \frac{z}{x^3+2xyz} \geq \frac{x}{y^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{y}{z^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{z}{x^3+\frac{2}{27}} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow P \geq \frac{27}{2} (x+y+z) - \frac{27}{2}\left(\frac{x\cdot y^3}{y^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{y\cdot z^3}{z^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{z\cdot x^3}{x^3+\frac{2}{27}}\right)$$
AM-GM: $$y^3+\frac{2}{27}=y^3+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{27}\geq 3\cdot\sqrt[3]{y^3\cdot\frac{1}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{27}}=\frac{y}{3}$$
Similar we have $$\frac{27}{2}\left(\frac{x\cdot y^3}{y^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{y\cdot z^3}{z^3+\frac{2}{27}} + \frac{z\cdot x^3}{x^3+\frac{2}{27}}\right) \leq \frac{81}{2}\left(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow P \geq \frac{27}{2} - \frac{81}{2}\left(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\right)$$
Now we need prove $$\frac{81}{2}\left(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\right)\lt \frac{27}{2} -\frac{15}{2} = 6$$
$$\Leftrightarrow xy^2+yz^2+zx^2 < \frac{4}{27}$$

I was stuck here. Help me, thank you so much.

Comment: Use buffalo way to prove the last inequality

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore oh but i dont have any idea... could you show me ?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore oh amazing, thank you so much. Have a good day. Love you so much :D